# Adding object prototypes dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shared-libraries, prototype

Ordinarily in standards JavaScript projects I have a series of `Date/Array/String.prototype` functions I used regularly and declare using a utilities file.

Trying to use a similar method in Google Apps Script, I'm setting up a library but object prototypes don't carry across when the library is loaded, and aren't recognised when they'd declared in the library and called from a function in the library.

E.g. In library file:

```
Array.prototype.test = function(){
  console.log('test prototype');
}
```

In file library is used, calling `[].test()` would error as undefined. The same calling a function in the library with this in it.

Comment: Specify what exactly your question is...?

Comment: I have read somewhere (I have not the reference at this time) that nowadays is discouraged to modify the prototypes of built-in objects likes Array. Please add brief description of the purspose of your Google Apps Script library.

Comment: pgSystemTester - I want to use a library function to add prototypes to multiple GAS files from a single source.

 
Rubén - Yes I've read similar but found them still much easier for implementation. The library is just a generic file of functions I use quite regularly in most my projects.